# Conflict between @FormParam and ${param}

Tags: jsp, jax-rs, form-parameter

I can use Expression Language to print a POST form value from current request in my view:

```
<p>Foo Name: ${fn:escapeXml(param.fooName)}</p>
```

But `param.fooName` EL variable is no longer populated when I capture form data into a Java variable using the `@FormParam` annotation in my controller:

```
@FormParam("fooName") String fooName
```

Full flow goes like this:

1. Browser submits form to `http://localhost:7101/myapp/rs/foo/new`:

   ```
   @POST
   @Path("/new")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
   public Response saveNew(
       @FormParam("fooName") String fooName // <---
   ) {
       Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       // Do stuff here
       return Response.ok(new Viewable("/foo/new", map)).build();
   }
   ```
2. View is rendered from `new.jsp`:

   ```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
   <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
   <p>Foo Name: ${fn:escapeXml(param.fooName)}</p>
   ```

If I remove the `@FormParam("fooName") String fooName` line then `${fn:escapeXml(param.fooName)}` contains form data again.

Is there a way to access form data in both locations (Java controller and JSP view)?

Comment: "Capture"? When exactly does this happen? Before or after the ${param} is printed? If before then you're probably simply not at all sending it to your controller. Usually you use input fields in HTML for this.

Comment: @BalusC First `saveNew()` is called and then it renders the HTML view. I'll edit the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug or feature, `@FormParam` seems to have side effects. However, form data is available at `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` so:

```java
@POST
@Path("/new")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response saveNew() {
    // null when it doesn't exist (no exception thrown)
    String fooName = request.getParameter("fooName");

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    // Do stuff here
    return Response.ok(new Viewable("/foo/new", map)).build();
}
```

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<p>Foo Name: ${fn:escapeXml(param.fooName)}</p>
```